# How do you decompose an arbitrary quantum state into its corresponding projection subspaces such that their direct sum is the quantum state?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I understand that every Hilbert space $H$ can be decomposed into two mutually orthogonal subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ whose direct sum is $H$.

Therefore, every vector $v\in H$ can be decomposed into $v_1\in H_1$ and $v_2\in H_2$ such that direct sum of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $v$.

I just want to see the mathematical procedure for an arbitrary quantum state.

Comment: I think you're looking for the Schmidt Decompositon. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is finite-dimensional (e.g. $H$ is the state space of a qubit), the procedure amounts to expanding the quantum state in an appropriately chosen basis.

Choose an orthonormal basis $|u_1\rangle, \dots |u_k\rangle$ of $H_1$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis $|u_1\rangle, \dots, |u_k\rangle, |u_{k+1}\rangle, \dots, |u_n\rangle$ of $H = H_1\oplus H_2$. Expand $|v\rangle$ in the basis

$$
|v\rangle = \underbrace{a_1 |u_1\rangle + \dots a_k |u_k\rangle}_{|v_1\rangle\in H_1} + \underbrace{a_{k+1} |u_{k+1}\rangle + \dots + a_n |u_n\rangle}_{|v_2\rangle\in H_2}
$$

to see that $|v\rangle = |v_1\rangle + |v_2\rangle$ is the desired decomposition.

---

If $H$ is infinite-dimensional (e.g. $H$ is the state space of a [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)), we can use projectors instead of a basis.

Let $P_k$ denote the orthogonal projector onto $H_k$ for $k=1,2$. Note that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are eigenspaces of $P_1$ associated with eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ respectively and of $P_2$ associated with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ respectively. Consequently, $H$ is the eigenspace of $P_1+P_2$ associated with eigenvalue $1$. Therefore, $P_1+P_2 = I$.

Now, let $|v_1\rangle = P_1|v\rangle$ and $|v_2\rangle = P_2|v\rangle$. Then,

$$
|v\rangle = I |v\rangle = P_1|v\rangle + P_2|v\rangle = |v_1\rangle + |v_2\rangle
$$

is the desired decomposition.